# How to find value and index of the minimum value of an array in Julia?

Tags: julia, minimum

I have a 5-element array,

```
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 0.7720227280667112
 0.2220636729556234
 0.2917295078541099
 0.0673233060720263
 0.11171893016863099
```

I want to get the minimum value (0.06) and its index! How can I do it?

Comment: It's a bit concerning that you have a numeric array with eltype `Any`, which is very far from optimal. You should find out why that has happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[findmin`][1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.findmin) function like this:

```
 julia> a = [0.7720227280667112; 0.2220636729556234; 0.2917295078541099; 0.0673233060720263; 0.11171893016863099]
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.7720227280667112
 0.2220636729556234
 0.2917295078541099
 0.0673233060720263
 0.11171893016863099

julia> findmin(a)
(0.0673233060720263, 4)
```